# django 1.7 makemigrations requires a dependency that I attempted to remove

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-migrations

I'm upgrading a django project from 1.6.11 to 1.7.9. I use DRF 2.4.4. Once everything is working fine, I'll upgrade to DRF 3.x

I started using django-oauth2-provider, but it can not work with django 1.7, so I'm moving to django-oauth-toolkit.
for the record, it does not work because HttpResponse does not accept `mimetype` anymore. it has to be 'content_type'. PRs for django-oauth2-provider are abandoned.

I pip installed it and added the oauth app to INSTALLED_APPS. Their [docs](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#sync-your-database) suggest using `syncdb` and then `migrate`, although [Django 1.7 deprecated syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations). I tried to migrate it with `./manage migrate oauth2_provider` unsuccessfully. It keeps reporting:

```
ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: provider
```

`provider` happens to be the old module for oauth, that was coupled with 2 of my apps.
I removed it from INSTALLED_APPS, commented all imports and usages of its classes, changed the model that had a FK to `provider.oauth2.models.Client` (I removed that field), and tried again. I got the same error.

The initial migration of one of the apps seems to be the only valid code that uses `provider` :

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('contenttypes', '0001_initial'),
        ('provider', '__first__'),
    ]
```

however, after this migration I removed that field. With South I'd probably do `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto` and then `migrate`.
However, when I try to `makemigrations myapp` I get the same error.

I'm totally lost. How can I get rid off the old oauth module and get the new one? Do I have to run `makemigrations` for oauth2_provider or just `migrate`? My guess is that only `migrate`. Why can't I make a migration with the changes in myapp model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me. Try manually removing the "provider" app line in initial migration that refers to it. Alternately, you can delete all migrations and run "makemigrations" from scratch (remember, for initial migrations you have to do it once for every individual app).

Comment: Thanks, I actually removed that migrations and their dependant ones and created them again. I wanted to have a commit with the transition from south to makemigrations and nothing more, but it would not work.